# Connect points and store point info in line attributes

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have a point shapefile where I want to connect all points (25 points that makes 600 pairs).

As a result, I need a line shapefile with attribute table that contains points lying on the line.

e.g.

```
lineID    pointID1    pointID2
  1          25          16
```

I've tried few plugins including points2one, MMQGIS, etc., but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this result using a python script that loops twice through the point layer, fetch the two points and construct a line.
The solution below removes duplicates (that it, line A -> B is consider the same as B -> A).

The output has the same CRS as the input. Make sure to edit the constant with the proper point ID column name

[image: Point connector output]

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

#Purpose: using the selected point layer, create a new scratch layer
#         containing a line between each pair of points and record the point ID

#***********Constants
#
SOURCEID = 'ID'

LINEID = 'lineID'
POINTID1 = 'pointID1'
POINTID2 = 'pointID2'
#
#***********

srclayer = iface.activeLayer()
crs = srclayer.crs().toWkt()

# Create the output layer
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs='+ crs, 'connector_lines' , 'memory')
outdp = outLayer.dataProvider()

#add the two point ID field
outdp.addAttributes([QgsField(LINEID, QVariant.Int),
                     QgsField(POINTID1, QVariant.Int),
                     QgsField(POINTID2, QVariant.Int)])
outLayer.updateFields()


#get the field index
srcIDfldidx = srclayer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(SOURCEID)
outLineIDfldidx = outdp.fieldNameIndex(LINEID)
outID1fldidx = outdp.fieldNameIndex(POINTID1)
outID2fldidx = outdp.fieldNameIndex(POINTID2)

lineIDcnt = 0

#loop through the points (1st point)
for feat1 in srclayer.getFeatures():
    geom1 = feat1.geometry()

    #statement for selecting the 2nd points with a greater ID to avoid duplicates
    # to keep them, change the expresion to ' <> '
    exp = QgsExpression(SOURCEID + ' > ' + str(feat1.attributes()[srcIDfldidx]))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
    #Select only the points having the specified value
    feat2lst=srclayer.getFeatures(request)

    #loop through the points (2nd point)
    for feat2 in feat2lst:
        lineIDcnt +=  1
        geom2 = feat2.geometry()

        #create the line
        connector = QgsFeature(outLayer.pendingFields())
        connector.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geom1.asPoint(),
                                                        geom2.asPoint()]))

        #record the IDs
        res = connector.setAttribute(outLineIDfldidx, lineIDcnt)
        res = connector.setAttribute(outID1fldidx, feat1[srcIDfldidx])
        res = connector.setAttribute(outID2fldidx, feat2[srcIDfldidx])

        #add the feature to the layer
        res = outdp.addFeatures([connector])

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)

print "Done .. "
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way is to:

- Create a virtual layer with a self cross join
- Save the virtual layer as a shapefile
- Use the field calculator to add the lineid:

> ```
> SELECT 
>    p1.pointid p1id, 
>    p2.pointid p2id,
>    MakeLine(p1.geometry, p2.geometry) geometry 
> FROM mypoint p1 CROSS JOIN mypoint p2  
> WHERE p1.pointid > p2.pointid
> ```

Here is how it looks like in QGIS Virtual Layers dialog.

[image]

Save the virtual layer to a shapefile. Then add the lineid column to the shapefile:

[image]

You could generate the lineid in the sql code skipping the last two steps. I could not get it working. Perhaps someone else can.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**WKT FIELD BASED SOLUTION**

- In Excel for example, create a table witht the Point start and end coordinates as below :

[image: Excel]

- Create a new colum named WKT
- Populate this column with a formula : use [CONCATENATE command](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excelformulas/using-concatenate-to-combine-names/1/) to create the following syntax for each line from your previous columns :

  LineString(POINT_START_X POINT_START_Y,POINT_END_X, POINT_END_Y)
- The CONCATENATE command should be like this:

  *=CONCATENATE("Linestring(";D2;" ";E2;",";F2;" ";G2;")")*
- You should obtain something like this in the last column :

  LineString(408963.1289 6708565.47,409267.9769 6708383.844)
- Save as Excel to keep your formula, then save as CSV file
- In QGIS, add a CSV layer like below - don't forget to check if QGIS has found that you put a WKT field :

[image: Import CSV]

There you go :

[image: Ending]

- As it's a csv file, you can still regenerate it any time you need.

**GEOMETRY CREATOR BASED SOLUTION (less good)**

The following solution allows you to manage your lines creation from Excel. The downside is that is mainly visual : you can't label your layer with the line ID on the line as the label is based on the start point.

- in your line list in excel (for example), add point 1 and point 2 coordinates (join it if necessary and use VLOOKUP in Excel) to get a table like below, with a point start coordinates and point end coordinates :

[image: Link Points table]

- In QGIS add your CSV file (or install the Spreadcheet plugin and add directly the data from Excel)
- Choose Point 1 columns coordinates to create a point layer
- You will get a point table with all start points
- Choose a Geometry generator style
- Choose Linestring Geometry type
- Enter this formula that will interactively create your lines from your Excel sheet or CSV file (just need to change thye name of field accordingly to your needs)

  make_line(make_point("Pt1_xcoord","Pt1_ycoord"), make_point("Pt2_xcoord","Pt2_ycoord"))

[image: Link lines generator]

And there you go :

[image: Link point lines]