# Visualizing Drop Off and Pick Up Points

Tags: qgis, point, points-to-line

I've mapped about 10,000 pick up and the corresponding drop off points. I wanted to connect each pick up point to it's respective drop off point with a line. What is the best way to go about doing this in QGIS? If this is not practical or if there is a better visualization method that someone knows of I am welcome to recommendations as well. I have tried using the plugin MMQGIS and its function Create - Hub Lines. I have also tried using Points2One function but none of them seem to do what I want (which I know from google searching has been done before, although on a smaller scale).

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: How do you have your points? do you have an id for each pick up point that matches with the id of the drop off point? you could share a sample of them

Comment: please have a look to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242524/connect-points-and-store-point-info-in-line-attributes. It might help you