# QGIS points or line vertex

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

Hi I have a sequence of points in QGIS and each of them has its attributes. For my application, I may need to manually edit them by dragging them around in the canvas. It would be much easier for me if the points are shown as CONNECTED, for example, a line. Then I can easily drag and align them.

One thing I tried is connect them into a line using whatever plugins. However, after converting from point feature to line feature, I have lost all my attributes of the points. Because it is a line feature now with line attributes. (all points become the vertices of the line).

I geuss to keep all the attributes of my points, I need to keep them as point feature rather than a line feature, but just show them in canvas as connected. Is this possible in QGIS? Or any other solutions would be welcomed.

Comment: related: [Connect points and store point info in line attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/242524/84870)

Comment: For this performance you don't need to connect them as line. You can drag them all together by using, in 'Editing Mode', 'Move Features' tool from **Digitizing Toolbar**.

Answer (score 1):

For this performance you don't need to connect them as line. You can drag them all together (selected to move) by using, in 'Editing Mode', 'Move Features' tool from **Digitizing Toolbar**. For instance, after selecting all points to move:

[image]

After moving them all together to a new desired position:

[image]

If you are satisfied with result, you can commit changes to preserve them. It can be observed that it was also preserved all fields in its attributes table.

Comment: Hi @xunilk, thanks very much for the answer and the visualizations. However, this is not what I want. My data is all about road lanes, curb lines, etc. even though they are all point features. For one lane line, I always have to manually align them like to a straight line or a smooth arc, etc. Without the view of the points connected together, it is really hard to determine if they are well aligned or not just using eyes.